# Help in Apostol Vol 1 integration review exercise

Tags: calculus, integration

5.11.9

Show that

$$\displaystyle \int_0^x{\frac{\sin(t)}{t+1}\ dt} \geq 0$$
$\forall x\geq 0 $

My attempt -

By 2nd mean value theorem,

$\displaystyle \int_0^x{\frac{\sin(t)}{t+1}\ dt} = \frac{1}{0+1} (1 - \cos(c)) + \frac{1}{x+1}(\cos(c) - \cos(x)) = 1 - \frac{x}{x+1}\cos(c) - \frac{\cos(x)}{x+1} $

But now how to show the above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By partial integration, $$\int^x_0\frac{\sin t}{t+1}\,dt=\frac{1-\cos x}{x+1}+\int^x_0\frac{1-\cos t}{(t+1)^2}\,dt.$$ Everything on the RHS is $\ge0$ for $x\ge0.$
Remark: this device works for every integral $\int^x_0f(t)\,\sin t\,dt,$ where $f$ is positive, differentiable and monotone decreasing. The device of @robjohn wouldn't need differentiability, so it's (potentially) more general.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{2k\pi}^{(2k+1)\pi}\frac{\sin(t)}{t+1}\,\mathrm{d}t+\int_{(2k+1)\pi}^{(2k+2)\pi}\frac{\sin(t)}{t+1}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin(t)}{t+2k\pi+1}\,\mathrm{d}t-\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin(t)}{t+(2k+1)\pi+1}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\pi\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin(t)}{(t+2k\pi+1)(t+(2k+1)\pi+1)}\,\mathrm{d}t
\end{align}
$$
That is, at the end of each interval of decrease, the integral is positive.

Comment: @Khosrotash: Thanks! This is very similar to the [Alternating Series Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) telling us that all partial sums are positive if the first term is positive.

Comment: What happens when $\displaystyle{x \over 2\pi}$ $\texttt{isn't}$ an integer ?.

Comment: @FelixMarin: there is an interval of increase, $[2k\pi,(2k+1)\pi]$, followed by an interval of decrease, $[(2k+1)\pi,(2k+2)\pi]$. What is shown above is that the contribution from the interval of decrease is not big enough to cancel the contribution from the previous interval of increase, so the value everywhere is non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> This proof is valid
>   $\ds{{\Huge\forall}\ x\ \in\ \mathbb{R}_{\ \geq\ 0}}$ !!! which
>   "$\underline{includes}$", as a particular case, "$\ds{x \over 2\pi}$ is an
>   $\ds{\underline{integer}}$" !!!.

\begin{align}
\left.\int_{0}^{x}{\sin\pars{t} \over t + 1}\,\dd t\,
\right\vert_{\ x\ \geq\ 0} & =
\int_{0}
^{\left\lfloor x/\pars{2\pi}\right\rfloor 2\pi + \left\{x/\pars{2\pi}\right\}2\pi}
{\sin\pars{t} \over t + 1}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{\left\lfloor x/\pars{2\pi}\right\rfloor 2\pi}
{\sin\pars{t} \over t + 1}\,\dd t +
\int_{0}^{\left\{x/\pars{2\pi}\right\}2\pi}
{\sin\pars{t} \over t + \left\lfloor x/\pars{2\pi}\right\rfloor 2\pi + 1}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\left\lfloor{x \over 2\pi}\right\rfloor\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin\pars{t}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\left\lfloor{x/\pars{2\pi}}\right\rfloor - 1}
{1 \over t  + 2\pi n + 1}\,\dd t}^{\ds{\mc{I}_{1}}}
\\[2mm] & +\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\left\{x/\pars{2\pi}\right\}2\pi}
{\sin\pars{t} \over t + \left\lfloor x/\pars{2\pi}\right\rfloor 2\pi + 1}
\,\dd t}
_{\ds{\equiv\ \mc{I}_{2}}}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

**$\ds{\Large\mc{I}_{1} \geq 0:\ ?}$**
\begin{align}
\mc{I}_{1} & =
-\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin\pars{t}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\left\lfloor{x/\pars{2\pi}}\right\rfloor - 1}
{1 \over t  + \pars{2n + 1}\pi + 1}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
-\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\pars{t}\bracks{%
\sum_{n = 0}^{\left\lfloor{x/\pars{2\pi}}\right\rfloor - 1}
{1 \over t  + \pars{2n + 1}\pi + 1} -
\sum_{n = 0}^{\left\lfloor{x/\pars{2\pi}}\right\rfloor - 1}
{1 \over -t  + \pars{2n + 1}\pi + 1}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
2\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\pars{t}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\left\lfloor{x/\pars{2\pi}}\right\rfloor - 1}
{t \over \bracks{\pars{2n + 1}\pi + 1}^{\,2} - t^{2}}\,\dd t\
\bbox[10px,#ffe,border:1px dotted navy]{\Large\geq 0}
\end{align}

---

**$\ds{\Large\mc{I}_{2} \geq 0:\ ?}$**

1. It's clear that $\ds{I_{2} \geq 0}$ whenever
   $\ds{\bbx{0 \leq \braces{x \over 2\pi}2\pi \leq \pi}}$.
2. When $\ds{\bbx{\pi < \braces{x \over 2\pi}2\pi < 2\pi}}$:
   \begin{align}
   \mc{I}_{1} & =
   \int_{0}^{\pi}{\sin\pars{t} \over
   t + \left\lfloor x/\pars{2\pi}\right\rfloor 2\pi + 1}\,\dd t +
   \int_{\pi}^{\left\{x/\pars{2\pi}\right\}2\pi}{\sin\pars{t} \over
   t + \left\lfloor x/\pars{2\pi}\right\rfloor 2\pi + 1}\,\dd t
   \\[5mm] & =
   \int_{0}^{\pi}{\sin\pars{t} \over
   t + \left\lfloor x/\pars{2\pi}\right\rfloor 2\pi + 1}\,\dd t -
   \int_{0}^{\left\{x/\pars{2\pi}\right\}2\pi - \pi}{\sin\pars{t} \over
   t + \pars{2\left\lfloor x/\pars{2\pi}\right\rfloor + 1}\pi + 1}\,\dd t
   \\[1cm] & = \overbrace{%
   \int_{0}^{\left\{x/\pars{2\pi}\right\}2\pi - \pi}\sin\pars{t}\bracks{{1 \over
   t + \pars{\left\lfloor x/\pars{2\pi}\right\rfloor + \color{#f00}{0}}2\pi + 1} -
   {1 \over
   t + \pars{\left\lfloor x/\pars{2\pi}\right\rfloor + \color{#f00}{1/2}}2\pi
   + 1}}\,\dd t}^{\large\geq\ 0}
   \\[2mm] & +\ \underbrace{%
   \int_{\left\{x/\pars{2\pi}\right\}2\pi - \pi}^{\pi}{\sin\pars{t} \over
   t + \pars{2\left\lfloor x/\pars{2\pi}\right\rfloor + 1}\pi + 1}\,\dd t}
   _{{\large \geq\ 0}.\ \mbox{See}\ \ds{1.}}\quad \bbox[#ffe,10px,border:1px dotted navy]{\Large \geq 0}
   \end{align}