# Prove that $\int^{x}_{0}{\frac{\sin(t)}{t+1}dt}>0$ if $x>0$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, proof-writing

> Prove that $\int^{x}_{0}{\frac{\sin(t)}{t+1}dt}>0$ if $x>0$.

This is problem 13.6 in Spivak's calculus textbook. Notably, I can't use FToC since that is in the next chapter.

I have solved this problem by splitting the interval into the set of $[2n\pi, 2(n+1)\pi]$ for  $n<x/2\pi$ and showing that each of these intervals must have a positive integral, but in showing this I had to prove $\int^{b}_{a}{f(x+c)}=\int^{b+c}_{a+c}{f(x)}$ ahead of a problem dedicated to this proof. Ultimately, I got to the answer in a way far more barbaric than intended.

Revisiting it, I can't think of a rigorous way to prove it with at least some elegance. I'm starting to think Spivak's intended answer was something hand-wavey like referencing the graph and how each area below the x-axis is smaller than the previous area above it.

Does anyone see a simple solution that I'm missing? Is there a way to turn my hand-wavey argument into a straight-forward proof shorter than what I've already done?

Comment: Something like this? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2343736

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3191597) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3594781).

Comment: @Gary Thank you. These solutions mirror my own (which I don't believe was in the book's consideration as I said), so I assume the intended answer really was the intuition behind the proof without the deets.